# Printing all possible combination of pairs of strings in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I stumbled across a free CodeAcademy course that covers Big O, and was getting through until I hit a specific question. It seems pretty easy, but I do not know why I am having such a tough time with it.

```
var people = ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "Dave", "Ed", "Mark", "Tom", "Lisa", "Sarah"];
```

Can anyone provide some insight on how I would go about printing out all of the possible combinations of pairs in this array? For example, it should print out like

```
Alice, Bob
Dave, Mark
Ed, Lisa
```

Also, it was saying that none of the pairs should ever pair with itself, or repeat an already existing pair. For example, if we already have "Ed, Lisa", it should never print "Lisa, Ed".

I started two for loops, then legit just had no idea where to go from there Frustrating!

```
var people = ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "Dave", "Ed", "Mark", "Tom", "Lisa", "Sarah"];

for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++){

   for(j = 0; j < people.length; j++) {
       // some fancy stuff here
    }
}
```

Solution doesn't really need to be in Javascript(but would be nice), perhaps PHP or Java would work too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use 2 `for` loops to get all combinations. Idea is that fix the first element and change the second element in each pair by iterating the list. Now the question is that from where should second loop start doing iterations?

We don't need a pair having same element so here `i can't be same as j (i!=j)` and we don't require a pair `(B,A)` is `(A,B)` is already in the list. So start doing iteration for the inner loop from `i+1` which assures that it won't print `(B,A)` if it has already printed `(A,B)`.

```
var people = ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "Dave", "Ed", "Mark", "Tom", "Lisa", "Sarah"];

var total_people = people.length;
for(var i=0;i<total_people;i++)
{
    for(var j=i+1;j<total_people;j++)
    {
        document.write(people[i]+" , "+people[j]+"<br>");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this actually works. I tested it in Java editor, and I didn't get the "Bob, Alice" you mentioned @Jonasw

Comment: @Daniel Zuzevich yes that was a mistake of mine, already edited my comment

Comment: No prob. Winner winner chicken dinner! This is a nice and easy solution, and can easily be transferred over to JS. thanks a lot. I will mark this as correct when Stack lets me after a 4 min wait time???

Comment: @DanielZuzevich I have changed the code So now It works in JS as well.